# require.cache is not empty before require

Tags: node.js, require

According to the description of require.cache

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
> (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
> exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
> file.

But When I've tested it in my node REPL, require.cache already has its object before require.

```
// test code
const utilsPath = require.resolve('../utils')

// logging the cache before require utils module.
console.log('-----')
console.log(require.cache[utilsPath])
console.log('-----')

const utils = require('../utils')
```

The console output is a Module object, and its key is the utilsPath.

How can require cache has that before require the corresponding module?

I've also tested with another module, but in that case, require cache was empty.

Any advice would really be appreciated!